# iOS memory leak Because of more number of image stored in Application Document

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-leaks

```
  -(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {

            UIImage * result;

            NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
            result = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            return result;
        }


    -(BOOL) saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName 
    {


        NSString * directoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString * extension = @"jpg";

        if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"])
        {
            [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
        }

        else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"])
        {
            [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
        }

        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }


for(int i =0; i<[imageNameArray count]; i++)
{
    UIImage *imageFromURL = [self getImageFromURL:imgURL];
    res = [self saveImage:imageFromURL withFileName:imgName];

}
```

Hi I have used above code to store many number of images from URL into Application Document.

It works perfectly but it returns memory error when try to store more number of images.

**failed (error code=3)**  error: can't allocate region  **set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug**

Can any one clarify how to solve this?

Also i had a doubt is Document directory's data occupied RAM Memory?

How to load more then 300 images into Application Document without Memory Error?

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: instead of looping in the main thread, use the different threads or using block  to write more images?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the compression size of the image to include more number of images. Instead of **1.0**, use **0.5** as compression value.

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
```

Comment: is UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) reduce the quality of image?

Comment: Yes slightly but unnoticeable on iphone screen - @Prabhu